# Is it possible to view source code held in Team Foundation Server (TFS) through a browser, with a permalink

Tags: git, tfs

Does Microsoft's Team Foundation Server (TFS 2012 or later) provide the ability to browse and obtain a permalink for source code (in the same way that github does, for example, for git code).

Ideally, this should be a permalink with respect to a specific changeset (commit), rather than HEAD.

I want this to provide traceability from initial requirement/specifications docs through to automated tests that demonstrate each of the spec's acceptance criteria as a passing test.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  Are you having some problem?  Do you need help constructing a URI?

Comment: That's good to hear it can be done, and yes, a URI is what I want.